# How to turn on android screen when received FCM push notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, wakelock

Is there a way to turn on android screen when received push notification from FCM or somewhere else?

I want it will turn on even if the app is in background, and even if the app is killed.

In addition, I want that the notification will make sound even if the device is in silent mode. Is it possible?

**edit**

I called this function in onMessageReceived(), after a few minutes of the screen being off, its not work, its not turns it back:

```kotlin
 private fun wakeApp() {
     val pm = applicationContext.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
     val screenIsOn = pm.isInteractive // check if screen is on
     if (!screenIsOn) {
         val wakeLockTag = packageName + "WAKELOCK"
         val wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
             PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or
                     PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or
                     PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, wakeLockTag
         )
         //acquire will turn on the display
         wakeLock.acquire()
         //release will release the lock from CPU, in case of that, screen will go back to sleep mode in defined time bt device settings
         wakeLock.release()
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can raise a high-priority notification. Whether that does the things that you seek will depend on the user and their settings within the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just call this function in your **onMessagesReceived** method. I also use this in my project.

```
private fun wakeApp() {
    val pm = applicationContext.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
    val screenIsOn = pm.isInteractive // check if screen is on
    if (!screenIsOn) {
        val wakeLockTag = packageName + "WAKELOCK"
        val wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
            PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK or
                    PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP or
                    PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, wakeLockTag
        )
        //acquire will turn on the display
        wakeLock.acquire()
        //release will release the lock from CPU, in case of that, screen will go back to sleep mode in defined time bt device settings
        wakeLock.release()
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add this permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And for making sound even in silent mode you can use the below code which will actually set the volume dynamically when notification is received and play the sound through **MediaPlayer**:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, 0);

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.example);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: After a few minutes of the screen being off, its not turns it back.. any idea?

Comment: Is the onMessagesReceived method being called? Also can you update the question with the code you added.

Comment: Yes, the onMessageReceived() being called.